# Is there another place to get a google-services.json?

Tags: android, google-signin

I tried clicking the `GET A CONFIGURATION FILE` link from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#get-config), but [the resulting page](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) just loads and loads.  This happens in Firefox and Chrome and on my phone.  Is there some other way to get a config file?

EDIT: I am getting these errors in Chrome Dev Console:

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv…ed%253Dtrue%26cntlbl%3DContinue%2BAdding%2BSign-In%26cntapi%3Dsignin&hl=en' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://console.developers.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').(anonymous function) @ script_foot.js:348n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try later, I have the same issue in my Firefox browser (in PC). Updated: Chrome is OK

Comment: Still happening for me, in chrome, in firefox, and on my phone.  I tried disabling my adblocker and VPN.  Still just loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found a workaround if anyone else is having this problem.

Based on the error message about being unable to display [https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv…ed%253Dtrue%26cntlbl%3DContinue%2BAdding%2BSign-In%26cntapi%3Dsignin&hl=en](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv%E2%80%A6ed%253Dtrue%26cntlbl%3DContinue%2BAdding%2BSign-In%26cntapi%3Dsignin&hl=en) in a frame... I just followed that link directly.

EDIT: None of the other links were working for me.  If you came searching for the console errors `Refused to display...`, this is the answer for you.  This bug seems to have been fixed for the google-services.json, so if you're just looking for the link, the highest-rated answer is the one you want.

Answer (score 46):

This might be a temporary issue due to network connectivity or something like that.

One solution would be to try again at a later point in time. This might be happening because you're trying to download the *google-services.json* for the sample project (com.google.samples.quickstart.signin).

If you want result now, you could follow the steps to integrate the Google Sign In into your app.

1. Create a new  empty android studio project/if you have an existing 
   project skip this step.
2. Use this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) and follow the onscreen instructions to generate the *google-services.json* for your app.

[image: Enable Google services for your app]

3. The app name here refers to your project name in [Google Developers
   Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). If you've already setup your Google developers console
   project for your android app, you can select that via the drop-down
   menu. If you have not created one, just enter a name and that
   project will be created for you in your developers console.
4. Select the google services you need for your project viz Google Sign
   In, Google Cloud Messaging, AdMob etc. In our case, we just selected
   Google Sign In.
5. You will be asked for SHA-1 hash. Follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) to get one.
6. Click on generate configuration files. Next screen you will be presented with an option to download google-services.json for your app. Download that and you're good to go.

[image: Download google-services.json]

7. Once you have the google-services.json, follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured) to     complete the Google Sign In.

### References

1. [Start Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating),
2. [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured).

Comment: The link in step 2 is where I'm having a problem.

Comment: That is not the same link.

Comment: Ah.  Well neither worked.  But I did figure it out.  Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 24):

You will get **"google-services.json"** as soon as you create a Firebase project.

But, in case you missed and forgot to download that, you can still get the JSON file from the existing project-

- Just select the project from firebase console.
- Head over to project settings
- scroll down (Yeah!, there it is!)

#### Screenshot :

[image: google-services.json]

Comment: Thanks for this. A lot of answers wanted to take me through the entire process when I converted a project and simply missed the download link.

Comment: That button isn't there

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) page:

> The Firebase console will help you download the google-services.json. In addition, the Quickstart guides for most APIs have instructions for generating this file. Once you have downloaded the google-services.json file, copy it into the app/ folder of your Android Studio project, or into the app/src/{build_type} folder if you are using multiple build types.

So go to [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), press add new project and follow instructions