# How to access google-services.json from web service for google analytics android

Tags: android, json, google-analytics

I want to access configuration file from web service for google analytics. I have a api which provide me the required information like in configuration file, in json format. Could you please suggest me an idea to achieve it? Is it possible to access the configuration information dynamically for google analytics?

Comment: I really don't think I understand your question. Google isn't going to give you access to config files for any of its services. Why would you need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I get a google-services.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/where-do-i-get-a-google-services-json)

Comment: @DaImTo yes correct. That configuration file is created while creating a project in developer account. We will use it in our app. But i have a requirement to get that information form web service. tat's y.

Comment: Download it and host it your self there is no way to access it from the web