# GoogleMap getMapAsync wont work in fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement googleMaps to my project, I simply added a new fragment and the following code. Currently I can display the map in my project but adding markers doesn't work and `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)` gives the following error message. Cannot resolve method `'getMapAsync(testCodes.project2.MapFragment)`.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
//    private MapView mapView;
    private Boolean mapReady = false;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);//remember getMap() is deprecated!


//    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Random position");
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        checkPermission("Permission", 1, 1);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


}
```

The xml of the fragment.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"></fragment>
```

Comment: You need to add googleservice.json. Hope you have added and the required things in the Manifest as well

Comment: I have done the required thing, as in getting the google sdk, api key etc. But not quiet sure what you mean with googleservice.json

. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"         android:value="myKey"/>

Comment: Try this link. It will guide you on how to do it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/where-do-i-get-a-google-services-json

Answer (score 1):

In xml file, you're using **class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"**, so in **MapFragment.java** you have to use **SupportMapFragment** instead **MapFragment**.

Change this:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);//remember getMap() is deprecated!
```

to:

```
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);//remember getMap() is deprecated!
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error on the declaration: 
`Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: try change your import from android.app.Fragment, to android.support.v4.app.Fragment