# How to generate google-services.json for new android project?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notification in my android app using GCM. But it seems GCM is deprecated and FCM is in place for the new apps. Whenever i am trying to go to google console it redirects me to firebase console for generating the configuration file. Is there any way i ca use the old GCM for my new app ? If possible, how can i generate the configuration file ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link it has steps follow it you will get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/where-do-i-get-a-google-services-json

Comment: Why do you not upgrade to FCM. The technology is still the same and you only have to replace the URL's for the push.