# Unable to download the google-services.json file for integrating with my android project

Tags: android, google-signin

I am integrating google sign-in to my app in android studio. I'm following this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) as suggested in many fora and tutorials.

I find a way to get the sha1 key of the project but when I paste on the prompt, I get the message "Something went wrong. Please try again". This happens every time I try to do the integration and because I am unable to integrate.

So, what's the work around to this problem? By the way I am doing this using Kotlin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try Logout From Google Account Then Re-Login And Try

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question lies in using firebase to integrate Google sign in with the android app. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In) must be followed.

The actual answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367870/where-do-i-get-a-google-services-json#34368739).

Thank you Ashvin.