# is google-services.json file is same for gmail integration and push notification?

Tags: android

I already added a 'google-services.json' file for push notification, now i need to add another 'google-services.json' file for gmail integration. Is it necessary to add another json file or both json files are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "gmail integration", but you don't need to generate google-services.json file every time for every google service. As I know you should configure a google console project by choosing number of needed services and generate this file for all of chosen services only once.

Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34368739/1652236